# Mad Python Numbers - hapax_legomena_ratio test

Tags: python

Alright so there is a file that tests my code(my code will be below)
I do get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Administrator/Documents/UTM/CSC108/A2_b/a2_self_test.py", line 46, in <module>
    0.7777777777777778),error_message
AssertionError: hapax_legomena_ratio on the text:

['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n', 'James Gosling\n']

 should return 0.7777777777777778
```

I don't understand how 0.7777777777777778 is not equal to 0.7777777777777778?!

my code for this specific problem:

```
def hapax_legomena_ratio(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    This function returns the hapax legomena ratio for text(HLR).
    HLR is the number of words that occur exactly once 
    divided by the total number of words.

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
    'James Gosling\n']
    >>> hapax_legomena_ratio(text)
    0.7777777777777778

    >>> text = [ "A guy walks into a bar and asks for 1.4 root beers.\n",
    "The bartender says\n",
    "I'll have to charge you extra, that's a root beer float\n",
    "The guy says\n",
    "In that case, better make it a double.\n" ] 
    >>> hapax_legomena_ratio(text)
    0.6756756756756757
    """
    names = { }
    word_counter = 0
    sentence = " ".join(text)
    replace_list = [",","-",":",";","<",">","*","(",")","[","]","\t","\r","\n"]
    for i in replace_list:
        sentence = sentence.replace(i, '').lower()
        for word in sentence.split():
            word_counter += 1
            if word in names:
                names[word] += 1
            else:
                names[word] = 1


    exactly_once = 0
    for name in names:
        count = names[name]
        if count == 1:
            exactly_once += 1


    return  exactly_once * 1.0 / word_counter
```

The test code is the following:

```
import builtins

def disable_input(*args):
    raise Exception("You should not call input!")

builtins.input = disable_input

import author_functions

def approx(v1, v2):
    """ (float, float) -> bool

    Return True iff v1 and v2 are approximately equal.
    """

    return v1-0.0001 < v2 < v1+0.0001


# Test avg_word_length.
text = [
    "James Fennimore Cooper\n",
    "Peter, Paul, and Mary\n",
]
error_message = "average_word_length on the text:\n\n" + repr(text) + \
    "\n\n should return 5.142857142857143"
assert approx(author_functions.avg_word_length(text), 5.142857142857143),\
    error_message


# Test type_token_ratio.
text = [
    "James Fennimore Cooper\n",
    "Peter, Paul, and Mary\n",
    "James Gosling\n"
]

error_message = "type_token_ratio on the text:\n\n" + repr(text) + \
    "\n\n should return 0.8888888888888888"
assert approx(author_functions.type_token_ratio(text), 0.8888888888888888),\
       error_message

# Test hapax_legomena_ratio.
error_message = "hapax_legomena_ratio on the text:\n\n" + repr(text) + \
    "\n\n should return 0.7777777777777778"
assert approx(author_functions.hapax_legomena_ratio(text),
              0.7777777777777778),error_message

# Test split_on_separators.
hooray = "Hooray! Finally, we're done."
thesplit = ['Hooray', ' Finally', " we're done."]

error_message = "split_on_separators(" + repr(hooray) + \
    ", '!,') should return " + repr(thesplit)
assert author_functions.split_on_separators(hooray, "!,") == thesplit,\
    error_message


# Test avg_sentence_length.
text = ["The time has come, the Walrus said\n",
        "To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n",
        "Of cabbages; and kings.\n",
        "And why the sea is boiling hot;\n",
        "and whether pigs have wings.\n"]

error_message = "avg_sentence_length on the text:\n\n" + repr(text) + \
    "\n\n should return 17.5"
assert approx(author_functions.avg_sentence_length(text), 17.5),\
    error_message


# Test avg_sentence_complexity.
error_message = "avg_sentence_complexity on the text:\n\n" + repr(text) + \
    "\n\n should return 3.5"
assert approx(author_functions.avg_sentence_complexity(text), 3.5), \
     error_message


# Test compare_signatures.
sig1 = ["a_string" , 4.4, 0.1, 0.05, 10.0, 2.0]
sig2 = ["a_string2", 4.3, 0.1, 0.04, 16.0, 4.0]
weight = [0, 11.0, 33.0, 50.0, 0.4, 4.0]

error_message = "compare_signatures on signatures \n" + repr(sig1) + "\n" + \
    repr(sig2) + "\n should return 12.000000000000007"
assert approx(author_functions.compare_signatures(sig1, sig2, weight),
              12.000000000000007), error_message


print("okay")
```

Comment: +1 just for the root beer joke, hadn't heard that before. But this is a FAQ.

Comment: Oops, sloppy reading on my part, I missed where you do exactly what it says in http://sopython.com/canon/36/

Answer (score 0):

Probably because real numbers are not exact. If you have

```
float a
float b
```

it's not a good idea to compare them directly like this:

```
if a == b:
    ...
```

You'll better do

```
if abs(a - b) < 0.00001:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately I can't change code that tests my above code. It was written by prof. and therefore there should be my mistake.

Comment: Well it's hard to do, when there are over 1000 people like me having questions :)

Comment: Ok, but you have no question for him, you have a bug report

Comment: I thought this was the problem at first, too. But the code does this correctly; it specifically doesn't check for numeric equality, but rather that the results are within a really small delta. In other words, it's already doing what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It an indentation error. :p

The word_count for loop is inside the for loop to rm non-word characters.

Comment: That's what I am doing here: exactly_once * 1.0 = I am getting 7.0

Comment: @b8ckwith hi, can you get a look at the test files? Once you know what assertion the test files make, maybe you can get your numbers exactly the same with it. Try to round your result to the same decimal place as the assertion does, maybe the prof is not using 7.0/9.0 as the result but 0.7777777777777778 instead.

Comment: This is weird, your prof is obviously using the right method to compare two floats. I have no idea now. :(

Comment: Well if you could look at my code, is there anything wrong that might cause that fault?

Comment: Well, I haven't read your code carefully because I took the comments in your function as your test results. But now I find the reason, your for loop to count words is inside your for loop to replace non-word characters!!!

Comment: Yes, i found it as well just a minute ago! thank you.

Comment: Remember to be careful :p

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is the solution (my mistake :) ) (hate python for that!!!)

instead

```
for i in replace_list:
        sentence = sentence.replace(i, '').lower()
        for word in sentence.split():
            word_counter += 1
            if word in names:
                names[word] += 1
            else:
                names[word] = 1
```

There should be this:

```
    for i in replace_list:
            sentence = sentence.replace(i, '').lower()
--->for word in sentence.split():
          word_counter += 1
                if word in names:
                    names[word] += 1
                else:
                    names[word] = 1
```

So basically wrong indentation. 
Thank you to everyone for help, tho.

Answer (score 0):

### Solved solution for Hapax Legomena Ratio (HLR) in python

```
def stripEnds(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
    converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

    >>> stripEnds('Happy Birthday!!!')
    'happy birthday'
    >>> stripEnds("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
    ' it's on your left-hand side'
    """
    from string import punctuation
    if s.endswith("\n"or"\t"or"\r"):
        s=s[:-1]
    St=(s.strip(punctuation))
    A= St.lower()
    return A

def hapax_legomena_ratio(text):

    Words = {}
    sentence = " ".join(text)
    sentence = stripEnds(sentence)
    splitList=sentence.split()

    for word in splitList:
        if word in Words:
            Words[word] += 1
        else:
            Words[word] = 1

    totalWords=[]
    for items in Words.items():
        totalWords.append(items)

    uniqueWords=[]
    i=0
    while i < (len(totalWords)):
        if (totalWords[i][1])==1:
            uniqueWords.append(totalWords[i])
        i=i+1

    return ( (len(uniqueWords)) / (len(splitList)) )
```

> **Test**

```
hapax_legomena_ratio(['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n', 'James Gosling\n'])
>>> 0.7777777777777778
```